# A lot activity in one layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am developing Restaurant menu app. I have 9 image button in activity_main.xml. For example: If when i clicked soup image button, the app will soup price and soup image in other layout. But i dont want create 9 layouts file for this. All of prices appear one layout. I didnt write method for this. I am waiting your help. Sorry for my bad english.

This is my menu.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:background="@drawable/corbalar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/corbalar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:background="@drawable/zeytinyaglilar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/zeytinyaglilar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:background="@drawable/spesiyaller"
    android:contentDescription="@string/spesiyaller"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/pideler"
    android:contentDescription="@string/pideler"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/salatalar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/salatalar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/kebaplar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/kebaplar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/tatlilar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/tatlilar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/mesrubatlar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mesrubatlar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/sicakicecekler"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sicakicecekler"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="degistirActivity"/>
```

This is the place I'll show information.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="tr.edu.fatih.nad0.com.kilislimenu.fiyatGoster">


//my items image
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gosterilecekyemek" />




//my items price 
<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton11"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is use an `intent` with `extras` to pass information of the clicked item to the activity. There's a couple of ways to do this:

1) Manually create an `OnClickListener` for each item (ideally, you'd generate your items from a SQLite database rather than having a static list).

Using an `OnClickListener` would look something like this:

```
ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent priceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), priceActivity.class);
        priceIntent.putExtra("price",6.99);
        priceIntent.putExtra("name","Hamburger");
        startActivity(priceIntent);
    }
});
```

Then in your `onCreate` method for `priceActivity.class`, you'd read the values like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
double price = extras.getDouble("price");
String name  = extras.getString("name");
```

2) Use the `onClick` attribute in your XML to process the information through an identifying `tag` or some such.

In your XML you can specify `android:onClick="myMethod"` as well as an identifying tag, like `android:tag="hamburger"`. Then you'd make your `myMethod`:

```
public void myMethod(View v) {
    String tagId = v.getTag().toString();
    // Create intent with extras like above
}
```

Again, ideally you'd be loading all of this information from a database so that you can easily access the information with fewer methods rather than manually entering the hard-coded data straight into the app.

Comment: Thank you so much. Intercalarily i want to set imagebutton background. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below link to workout with your problem.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Alternatively,

you can implement method like this on your button.

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
  String message = editText.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
```

On another Activity, you can receive Intent and Display your price.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Intercalarily i want to set imagebutton background. How can i do this?

Comment: follow this link.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imagebutton_control.htm